# Finding Mean curvature H of an intermediate isometric form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

An undefined *Frill* form shown here ( schematically in  appearance similar to  $ z = \cos x \cosh y $  but is not its exact isometric form ).. is isometric to the catenoid and helicoid.

*The Frill* is symmetric about $(xz, yz) $ planes seen with 4 waves, the helicoid 2 helical turns and catenoid with repeated scrolls.
$ z= f(x,y) $ in Monge form like the one pictured does not have $ K=-1$

The catenoid and helicoid inter-deformation consists of bending/twisting. The mapping and parametrization are known.

Please help find

- parametrization of the *Frill*
- and so its $H,$ with $K$ invariance.
- and its mapping separately to arrive at the catenoid and helicoid... by pure bending and pure twisting parametrizations starting at the Frill.
- K and H of  $ z = \cos x \cosh y $ for comparison.

EDIT1:

It is required to find if the isometric variant of *the Frill* with same first fundamental form metric is a *minimal surface $H=0 $* along with the catenoid and helicoid.

[image]

Comment: Is the Frill literally the graph of $z = \cos x \cosh y$?  If not, then what is its precise mathematical description?  Without a precise description, it's impossible to calculate $H$ and $K$.

Comment: It is cited only for purpose of approximate visualization. Even functions of $x,y$. From common  first fundamental form they all share the same $K$.

Comment: So, your question is to find a parametrization of a surface which is isometric to the helicoid (and catenoid), and somehow resembles the picture above? That is still rather vague.  I think more information regarding the Frill needs to be provided.

Comment: Yes,right. In order to physically get convinced about its existence a rubber model can be used deforming by your own hand to each state.I picked up a water bottle for the purpose and cut out parts not required . It should be thin rubber, else rigidity would  tend to remove formed edge waves.It has $K<0,$ not constant.  Afaik, the answer is not already available in standard text-books on differential geometry, –

Comment: The [**animation**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UW35Zmt_qOI) may help.